# How to add a production config when deploying a docker container?

Tags: python, docker

I used to deploy Python web applications on AWS EC2 instances with Ansible.

In my development environment, I use config from a module `local_config.py`, but in the deployment process, I use an Ansible task to replace this file with a production-ready config.

How do I do something similar when building a Docker image?

Answer (score 0):

You should copy your production-ready config file into the docker container as part of your image-building process (COPY directive in your dockerfile), and then proceed with the same deployment steps you would normally use.